# phonegap passar lista de conatos para mysql

Tags: php, ajax, apache-cordova

Estou tentando pegar a lista de contatos do celular e enviar através de ajax e php para o mysql. Esse é o código que estou usando:

```
 document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    function onDeviceReady() {
        var options = new ContactFindOptions();
        options.filter="";          // empty search string returns all contacts
        options.multiple=true;      // return multiple results
        filter = ["*"]; 
        navigator.contacts.find(filter, onSuccess, onError, options);
    }


function onSuccess(contacts) {  
    for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++){

var phoneNumbers = contacts[i].phoneNumbers;
//alert(JSON.stringify(phoneNumbers));

for (var j=0;j<phoneNumbers.length; j++){
//if(phoneNumbers[j].type == "mobile"){
//alert(phoneNumbers[j].value);

var jsonString = JSON.stringify(phoneNumbers[j].value);


 //var dataString ="title="+jsonString+"&insert=";
 var dataString = JSON.parse(jsonString);


//$("#contactList").append("<li><input type='text' name='box["+i+"]' id='box' value='"+dataString+"'></li>");
$("#contactList").append("<input type='text' name='name[]' id='name' value='"+phoneNumbers[j].value+"'>");
//$("#contactList").listview("refresh");

//}
}
}
}

    function onError(contactError) {
        //alert('onError!');
    }

 AJAX

    var fields = $('#myform').serialize();

    var jsonString = JSON.stringify(fields);
    console.log(fields);
    $.ajax(
    {
        url : "retorno.php",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {data : jsonString}, 
        cache: false,
        success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) 
        {

$('#stage2').html(data);

        }
    });

});
```

PHP

```
$name = $_POST['data'];
```

Se alguém puder ajudar, ficarei muito agradecido.

Comment: Ué teu PHP esta rodando dentro de um celular? Ou o PHP esta em um servidor externo?

Comment: Está rodando em um servidor fora. No lugar do url quando publiquei aqui não indiquei o caminho.

Comment: Mas então você passou `url : "http://site.com/retorno.php",` né?

Comment: exatamente. Só que não consegue inserir no BD os dados vindo do celular. Mas se eu preencher manualmente uma array de <input type="text" name="name[]" value="">  ele insere no BD de boa. Só não insere quando os dados vem do celular

Comment: Ressaltando que estou testando através do phoneGap developer utilizando um celular

Comment: Consegue pegar a requisição HTTP do celular no momento que a envia?

Comment: Sim. Inclusive, quando dou count no array ele insere o total de 1 no BD, quando na verdade eu tenho 10 contatos. Mas se eu inserir no App manualmente 4 numeros nos inputs, ele insere os 4 numeros corretamente. O problema é quando vem os dados co phoneNumbers[j].value.

Comment: Eu já entendi o problema, quero só saber se tem como depurar a requisição HTTP, é através disto que saberemos como os dados foram transmitidos. Se conseguir pegar o REQUEST, copia ele e cola aqui.

Comment: Não tem como depurar, infelizmente. Informação está passando, pois se eu dou count no Post ele retorna valor 1, só que na verdade eu tenho 10 contatos. A questão é: será que ele traz uma array com todos os contatos? se for isso, como posso pegá-la? Outra coisa, no retorno para o phoneGap em html ele printa o código fonte que está comentada no PHP, inclusive o fechamento do código php ?>

Comment: Guilherme, quando puder da uma resposta estarei aguardando. @GuilhermeNascimento